# How do i get an item from dynamodb table?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Im trying to check if an item exists in my dynamodb table using the code below:
I want to be able to run something once I can retrieve the item. The partition key is **envName** and the sort key is **configurationName**

```
package com.dev.newlibs;

//all relevant imports added here

public class updatenewCMDB {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        String tableName = "env_dashboard";
        String configurationName = "component";
        String configurationNameValue = "ec2";
        String envName = "env_Name";
        String envNameValue = "dev";
        String status = "status"; 
        String statusValue = "COMPLETE";

        DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();
            
            client.close();

            updateEnvDashboard(client, tableName, configurationName, configurationNameValue, envName, envNameValue, status, statusValue,);
    }

    public static void updateEnvDashboard(DynamoDbClient client,
                                         String tableName, 
                                         String configurationName,
                                         String configurationNameValue,
                                         String envName,
                                         String envNameValue,
                                         String status, 
                                         String statusValue,) throws Exception {

        
        //Get item to see if it exists
        HashMap<String,AttributeValue> itemToGet = new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();
        
        itemToGet.put(configurationName, AttributeValue.builder().s(configurationNameValue).build());
        itemToGet.put(status, AttributeValue.builder().s(statusValue).build());
        itemToGet.put(envName, AttributeValue.builder().s(envNameValue).build());


        GetItemRequest request = GetItemRequest.builder()
                .key(itemToGet)
                .tableName(tableName)
                .build();
        
        //run a get request and see what is returned. do something depending on what is returned
        
        try {
            Map<String,AttributeValue> returnedItem = client.getItem(request).item();
            if (returnedItem != null) {
                Set<String> keys = returnedItem.keySet();
                System.out.println("Amazon DynamoDB table attributes: \n");

                for (String key1 : keys) {
                    System.out.format("%s: %s\n", key1, returnedItem.get(key1).toString());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format("No item found with the key %s!\n");
            }
            
        } catch (DynamoDbException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
    }
}
```

When running this i get the error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

what am i missing here? i've tried to follow the getItem example from the official aws repo

Comment: Why did you put originally 4, now 3 attributes to `itemToGet`? DynamoDB items have 1 or 2 key attributes only (partition or partition+sort).

Comment: are you saying i only need the ```envName``` and ```configurationName``` for ```itemToGet```?

Comment: You have to supply the key attribute(s), with the correct type(s). I don't know for sure that DynamoDB will reject non-key attributes in a GetItem request but a) it would not surprise me at all and b) it doesn't make sense to send them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply the key attribute(s), with the correct type(s), when calling [GetItem](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#getItem-software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.GetItemRequest-).

You've included non-key attributes (`status`). When you supply non-key attributes, your GetItem request will fail with a ValidationException including this error message:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Modify your [GetItemRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/GetItemRequest.html) to only include key attributes (`envName` and `configurationName`), and ensure they have the correct data types (both strings).

To verify what's going on, it's often useful to confirm your assumptions using the awscli. Here's an example of how to issue that same GetItem call with the awscli:

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
    --table-name mytable \
    --key '{"envName":{"S":"env1"}, "configurationName":{"S":"config1"}}'
```

Some important background knowledge about DynamoDB: you cannot get an item without indicating its full key, which in your case is `envName` plus `configurationName`. If instead of a specific, single item, you actually want all items that have a given `envName` then you can issue a Query (instead of GetItem) with just the `envName` partition key. You cannot get/query a sort key, so you will not be able to query all items with a given `configurationName` ... unless you create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) on that sort key attribute and then indicate the GSI name when querying.

Comment: ok i've updated it to only use ```configurationName``` and i still get the same error. I know for a fact that these attributes are all string types too so idk what else i can do

Comment: You can't get an item without indicating the full key, which in your case is envName plus configurationName. If you want all items that have a given envName then you can issue a Query (instead of GetItem) with just the envName partition key. You can't get/query a sort key, unless you create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) on the sort key attribute.

Comment: the status var in this case was causing the issue here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look at using the Amazon DynamoDB enchanced client to obtain an item. Using the enhanced client, you can map client-side classes to DynamoDB tables. For more information, see [Using the DynamoDB Enhanced Client in the AWS SDK for Java 2.x.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html)

For example assume you want to get customer data from the Customer table.

[image]

Here is the **Customer** Java class.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSortKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.WriteBatch;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

/**
 * This class is used by the Enhanced Client examples.
 */

 @DynamoDbBean
 public class Customer {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private Instant regDate;

        @DynamoDbPartitionKey
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        };

        public void setId(String id) {

            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCustName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setCustName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Instant getRegistrationDate() {
            return regDate;
        }
        public void setRegistrationDate(Instant registrationDate) {

            this.regDate = registrationDate;
        }
    }
```

You can get a Customer record using this code:

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.getitem.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSortKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import java.time.Instant;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.getitem.import]

/*
 * Prior to running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with these columns:
 *   - id - the id of the record that is the key
 *   - custName - the customer name
 *   - email - the email value
 *   - registrationDate - an instant value when the item was added to the table
 *
 * Also, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class EnhancedGetItem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
                .build();

        String result = getItem(enhancedClient);
        System.out.println(result);
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.getitem.main]
    public static String getItem(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {
        try {
            //Create a DynamoDbTable object
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));

            //Create a KEY object
            Key key = Key.builder()
                    .partitionValue("id146")
                    .build();

            // Get the item by using the key
            Customer result = mappedTable.getItem(r->r.key(key));
            return "The email value is "+result.getEmail();

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return "";
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.getitem.main]
}
```

As you can see in this debug view, this code retrieves the Customer record.

[image]

Also - in the code example in your thread, you are closing the client before calling the method:

```
DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                .build();
            
            client.close(); // bug here

            updateEnvDashboard(client, tableName, configurationName, configurationNameValue, envName, envNameValue, status, statusValue,);
```